# How can I move a portal from a DNN 5.1 install to a DNN 7.3 install?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am working on consolidating DNN portals from various versions of DNN to the newest install I have at this time.

How do I take a DNN portal on DNN 5 (or even DNN4) and import into a DNN 7.3 host?   Will the skin be supported? break? content?  These are mostly content-rich portals so i want to move the portal content and skin over to the new host so its easier to maintain and have fewer installs that are outdated.  Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that will be easy to do. You'd probably be best served by doing the following.

1. Backup the DNN 5 site (files and database)
2. Restore the backup to a new IIS website/database
3. Upgrade that DNN 5 site to 7.3
4. Export a Portal Template from the upgraded site
5. Import that portal template into your production 7.3 environment.

Even that won't be guaranteed, you'll likely have modules that won't work, and the skin almost definitely won't work.

I would simply upgrade the site to 7.3 and fix what is necessary myself.

Comment: Thanks Chris, That's what i thought too  I appreciate the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to do step by step. First backup both  the code and the data base, after that upgrade to the last version 5.x, then to the first stable 6.x then to the last stable 6.x then to the first 7.x and then to the 7.4.
Good luck

As Chris said "Even that won't be guaranteed, you'll likely have modules that won't work, and the skin almost definitely won't work.

I would simply upgrade the site to 7.3 and fix what is necessary myself."